# Android Auto / Android Automotive application with Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-automotive

Is it possible to create application for Android Auto / Android Automotive using Jetpack Compose ? It's about simple app with audio files playing.

I've researched a lot of docs and didn't find any answer.

I need some explanations about that

Answer (score 2):

For an audio app, you'll primarily need to create a `MediaBrowserService` to enable playback and browsing on Android Auto and Android Automotive OS. See [Supported categories](https://developer.android.com/training/cars#supported-app-categories) for more details on the categories that Android Auto and Android Automotive OS support as well as the technologies used to build apps in those categories. For a sample audio media app, see [UAMP](https://github.com/android/uamp).

Comment: Thanks so much for important links ! Could you validate please my conclusion ? In automotive module i must specify configurations (Manifest file) like app category, then, in general, we can build ui part using different methods, in my case - Jetpack Compose, but depends of app category i must setup different services to process main functionality, like MediaBrowserService to play in car some audio files ?

Comment: That's mostly correct. The main thing to be aware of for media apps is that, except for optional sign-in and settings screens, what a user sees on screen isn't actually drawn by the app itself but by the system (Android Auto itself for Android Auto and the [Media Center app](https://source.android.com/docs/automotive/hmi/media/customization) for Android Automotive OS) using the metadata (e.g. track title, album image, etc.) they read from your MediaBrowserService.